# How can I use python variable (list) to populate values in select options

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-5

I have a variable in my python file 'myVariable' as a list and want to use to this to generate the options in my html file instead of hardcoding the values like below I want them to come from my variable in the Python file

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Large select example">
            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
          </select>
```

I am hoping I don't have to run python snip-it in the html file and can somehow import the variable in my html script from the Python file within the project.

Comment: try using a for loop for option values  {{ for i in myVariable }} and pass the i to the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask does use [`jinja2`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) for templates rendering, which has `for` loop and support argument unpacking, which could be used as follows

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index_view():
    options = [(1,"uno"),(2,"dos"),(3,"tres")]
    return render_template("index.html", options=options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>For Example</title></head>
<body>
    <form>
       <select name="square">
           {% for val, opt in options %}
           <option value="{{val}}">{{opt}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*(tested in Flask 2.3.2)*